How to show the following sequence of group homomorphism is exact?
Background
The following is taken from:  Graduate Course In Algebra, A - Volume 1 by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
....a short exact sequence of groups is just another way of talking about a normal subgroup and the corresponding quotient group.  However, even if $H$ is normal in $G$, knowing $H$ and $G/H$ does not determine $G$.  Here is an example:
$$0\xrightarrow{g_1}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{g_2}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{g_3}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{g_4}0$$
Questions:
I want to ask about how to show the above sequence as exact.
For a sequence of maps to be exact, we need $\text{Im }g_{i-1}=\text{ker }g_{i}$.
For the first pair of maps $g_1$, and $g_2$, we have $g_1(n)=n+p\mathbb{Z}$, $g_1(0)=p\mathbb{Z}$ and so $\text{Im }g_1=\{p\mathbb{Z}\}$. For the map $g_2$ being defined as $g_2(n+p\mathbb{Z})=(n+p\mathbb{Z}, n+p\mathbb{Z})$, $g_2(0+ p\mathbb{Z})=(0+ p\mathbb{Z}, 0+ p\mathbb{Z})=(p\mathbb{Z}, p\mathbb{Z})$, and $g_2(0+ p\mathbb{Z})=g_2(p\mathbb{Z})$, and $\text{ker }g_2=\{p\mathbb{Z}\}$  Hence $\text{Im }g_{1}=\text{ker }g_{2}$
for the second pair of maps $g_2, g_3$, we defined $g_3$ to be $g_3(n+p\mathbb{Z}, n+p\mathbb{Z})=n+p\mathbb{Z}$. We have $\text{Im }g_2=\{(n+p\mathbb{Z}, n+p\mathbb{Z})\}$.  But for the kernel of $g_3$, is it $\text{ker }g_3=\{(p\mathbb{Z},  n+p\mathbb{Z})\}$, or is it  $\text{ker }g_3=\{(n+p\mathbb{Z},  p\mathbb{Z})\}$,
for the third pair of maps $g_3, g_4$, we have the map $g_4(n+p\mathbb{Z})=0$ with $\text{Im }g_3=\{n+p\mathbb{Z}\}$  and $\text{ker }g_4=\{n+p\mathbb{Z}\}$, so $\text{Im }g_3=\text{ker }g_4$.
I am having trouble with the element $0$, is it suppose to $0+p\mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$ or is it simply defined as $0$. I feel like I am being inconsistent for the maps $g_1$ and $g_4$ in how I should be defining $0$.  Is like I have to change it to fit the intepretation of the sequence being exact.
Thank you in advance.

You're making things a little complicated by working with the cosets of the quotients directly. $g_1$ should just be the map $0 \to 0$. $g_2$ can be either $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times 0$ or the other way around. You want the image of $g_2$ to be the kernel of $g_3$ so depending on which $g_2$ you pick your choice of $g_3$ will be forced. $g_4$ is the zero map since $0$ is the trivial group.

This one is split.
